# displaying text of html entities

Tags: html, html-entities

so html entities like **&amp ;** (without space) will be converted to **&** when the browser renders the page. How do I display the text **&amp ;** (without space) on the page then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, put an ampersand and then amp; as shown below.

> &amp;amp;